# DIV height wont scale the way I want

Tags: html, css, dynamic, css-tables

http://telschowdesign.com/_JCM/ - Mock up 
http://telschowdesign.com/_JCM/index2.html - The fail

Pretty much I have these two side panels that I want to scale in height  as shown in the mockup. For what ever reason I can't get them to do that using my current CSS. I've tried using `height=100%` but that isn't working. I do not want to use a static measurements such as 700px etc etc

I know this can be done using tables instead but I want to be able to use the same content for a mobile version for the CSS.

Comment: i think you have very large paragraph at header that is the problem just decrease the font size

Answer (score 1):

`height:100%` doesn't mean what you think it does. It means the element you set this style to, it will take up 100% of the height of its containing element, not 100% of its children's height.

What you want to achieve is a very typical 3 column layout. Here is a link to an example of how to do it:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm

Answer (score 0):

The height of a div is the height of the content.

You can try using line-height css property on your div.

```
line-height: normal; 
line-height: 3.5;    /* <number> values */
line-height: 3em;    /* <length> values */
line-height: 34%;    /* <percentage values */
line-height: 50px;   /* <Pixel> values */

line-height: inherit
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Replace the css of the **#container** id :

```
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Then your content will be centered ;), if you need it, you can also use a CSS framework like 960grid.css, you will be desktop screen + mobile + iPad compatible and more productive and adaptive ;)

Then, you've a js error on node :

```
<body onload="javascript:panels()">
```

**panels() function** does not exists... ;)

Comment: yeah i was trying to just use JS to adjust the height of the panels but that didnt work thanks for the notice

Answer (score 0):

You can use Divs and % on your site master and the following css

## navigationbar

{ float: right; height:40px; }

## maincontent

{ float: left; width: 60%; }

and your HTML will look like this...

div id="navigationbar"
div id="maincontent"

and these can be inside one big Div. Hope it helps